# Awk or Sed: Return lines between two instances of the same pattern

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
-+- beginning text
hey there
hi there
ho there
-+- ending text
other stuff
that is
immaterial for
my purposes
```

I want to only grab the lines between the -+- patterns, so it will return:

```
hey there
hi there
ho there
```

The standard awk way:

```
awk '/beginning text/ {flag=1;next} /ending text/ {flag=0} flag {print}'
```

Works great as long as "beginning text" and "ending text" are different patterns.

Alas, for what I need, "Beginning text" and "Ending text" can change.  The only consistent part of the two lines are the "-+-".  All the rest of the text in the file can be completely different; I can't rely on any consistent patterns.  The only reliable text is the -+-.  And the awk fails when the two strings are identical.

Any ideas for how I can returns the lines between two discrete instances of the same pattern exclusive of the lines containing the patterns?  Doesn't have to be awk, just something that will work in a bash shell script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the pattern is the same and you don't want the pattern lines printed out then just combine the two patterns by inverting the flag each time you see the pattern.

```
awk '/^-\+-/ {flag=!flag; next} flag {print}'
```

Comment: Holy heck, that is simple and brilliant.  No idea why I didn't think of it.  :)   Thanks Etan.

Comment: Nice! Note you can even omit the `{print}` part, since `flag` evaluating as True will make `awk` perform its default action: `print`.

Comment: And if you need to print only the first N instances: `awk '/Matches/ { flag=!flag; count+=1; next } flag && count < 2 {print}'`

Answer (score 3):

```
cat ttt
aaaa
bbbb
ccccc
bbbb
xxxxx
gggg
awk '/bbb/ {flag=1-flag; next} {if (flag) {print $0}}' ttt
ccccc
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^-+-/,/^-+-/ { /^-+-/! p; }'
```

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/^-\+-/ { flag++; next } flag % 2'
```

Using `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'if (/^-\+-/) { $a ^= 1; next } print if $a'
```

Using new(ish) `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print if /^-\+-/.../^-\+-/ and !/^-\+-/'
```

Using `bash`:

```
#! /bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^-\+- ]]; then
        let flag^=1
        continue
    fi
    if [ $flag -ne 0 ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$line"
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
hey there
hi there
ho there
```

Answer (score 2):

For a generic use (same or different pattern for start/stop)

```
awk '#     Start pattern
     $0 ~ /^-\+-/ {flag=1;next}
     #     Stop   pattern
     $0 ~ /^-\+-/ {flag=0;next}

     flag { print}
    ' YourFile
```

note: `+` need to be escaped in regex for litteral use

Adapted based on remark of @fedorqui

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two patterns. Also, `$0 ~ /regex/` can be simplified to just `/regex`. Same with `print` instead of `print $0`.

Comment: i agree in this case, i reply to the "any regex" where in this specific case it is the same. I assume, the extended question will not create 2 script depending on same or different pattern (i adatp due to error if 2 starting/stoping parttern occur and simplify the last $0)